# Tap and hold menu to delete item

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I'm trying to create a menu that appears when you tap and hold an item in the GridView. The menu has an option to delete the item from the source of the GridView. When I tap on the "Delete" option, how do I reference the item that was originally clicked on? Here's the Xaml:

```
<GridView Name="SharedBooksGrid" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ItemClick="BookClicked" IsItemClickEnabled="True" Grid.Row="3" Holding="SharedHold"  RightTapped="RightTapHold">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="250" Width="400">
                    <Image Source="{Binding BookImage}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                    <Rectangle Opacity="0.35" Fill="Black" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding BookName}" FontSize="29" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10" Foreground="White" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
            <MenuFlyout x:Name="SharedMenu">
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Make Default" />
                <MenuFlyoutSeparator />
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete" Click="DeleteShared_Tapped" />
            </MenuFlyout>
        </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
    </GridView>
```

And the code behind:

```
private Book deleteAccessBook;
private void RightTapHold(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    Point point = e.GetPosition(sender as UIElement);
    SharedMenu.ShowAt(sender as UIElement, point);
}

private async void DeleteShared_Tapped(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    deleteAccessBook = e.OriginalSource as Book;
    bookAccessCollection = await BookAccessTable.ToCollectionAsync();
    foreach (var item in bookAccessCollection)
    {
        if (item.UserId == App.MobileService.CurrentUser.UserId)
        {
            if (item.BookId == deleteAccessBook.id)
            {
                await BookAccessTable.DeleteAsync(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My thought was that the e.OriginalSource would contain the item that was tapped on, but the exception gets thrown when trying to find the id from deleteAccessBook. Thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to get your *Book* by getting the *DataContext* of holded element:

```xml
<GridView Name="SharedBooksGrid" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ItemClick="BookClicked" IsItemClickEnabled="True" Grid.Row="3" Holding="SharedHold">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="250" Width="400" RightTapped="RightTapHold">
                <Image Source="{Binding BookImage}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                <Rectangle Opacity="0.35" Fill="Black" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding BookName}" FontSize="29" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10" Foreground="White" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        <MenuFlyout x:Name="SharedMenu">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Make Default" />
            <MenuFlyoutSeparator />
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete" Click="DeleteShared_Tapped" />
        </MenuFlyout>
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
</GridView>
```

```cs
private Book deleteAccessBook;
private void RightTapHold(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    var holdedElement = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
    if (holdedElement == null) return;
    deleteAccessBook = holdedElement.DataContext as Book;
    SharedMenu.ShowAt(holdedElement);
}

private async void DeleteShared_Tapped(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (deleteAccessBook == null) return;
    bookAccessCollection = await BookAccessTable.ToCollectionAsync();
    foreach (var item in bookAccessCollection)
    {
        if (item.UserId == App.MobileService.CurrentUser.UserId)
        {
            if (item.BookId == deleteAccessBook.id)
            {
                await BookAccessTable.DeleteAsync(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm still getting deleteAccessBook as null though.

Comment: @robbiestells I've taken one more look at your code. In XAML put your flyout inside ItemTemplate, so that it gets context of item, you may subscribe to Grid tapped event (itemtemplate) instead of the whole gridview.

Comment: If I put the flyout inside the ItemTemplate, I don't believe I can reference it in the code behind. SharedMenu can't be found after I move it.

Comment: @robbiestells That is normal - if you have general flyout in few items - which one should be shown? I've edited code a little - xaml and cs - the datacontext is known from itemtemplate's grid and then passed by variable to flyout's event. There are also couple of other ways to achieve this.